# regex jquery remove all double spaces

Tags: jquery, regex

Hi I have this code, I want it to remove all the double spaces from a text area, but it will only remove the first occurrence each time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#article").blur(function(){
    ///alert($(this).val());
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s\s+/, ' '));
  });
});
```

I've also tried removeAll(), but it won't work at all. any help would be great, thanks.
I have a live example online at http://jsbin.com/ogasu/2/edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [*g* modifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/RegExp#Parameters) in your regular expression to match and replace globally:

```
/\s\s+/g
```

Otherwise only the first match will be replaced.

By the way, as of jQuery 1.4 and later you can also [provide `val` a function](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex,%20value) that performs the replacement:

```
$(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
});
```

That will save you a second call of `$(this).val`.

Answer (score 3):

```
.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '));
```

note the **g**